# executing a python code located in a subfolder

Tags: bash

I have a directory called `NHOME`. In this directory there is a folder named `subFolder`. It's like this:

```
/NHOME/subFolder
```

In `NHOME` directory I'm executing a bash script which intends to execute a python code located in `subFolder`. I have problem doing this. I tried something like this:

```
./subFolder/file.py
```

but it didn't work. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `python ./subFolder/file.py`?

Comment: Yes, I got this error: ImportError: No module named parse, while it works when I  execute it inside subFolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pwd` to get the script's location instead of the relative `./`

```
pythonScript="$PWD/subFolder/file.py"
```

To run:

```
#!/bin/bash
"$PWD"/subFolder/file.py
```

Note: The `"` around `$PWD` are needed if the path contains spaces ()

Comment: The working directory is available in the variable `PWD`. This gives the directory where the script itself is stored, which may or may  not be the same as the working directory.

Comment: `$PWD` is more efficient than `$(pwd)` -- the former is just a variable lookup inside the shell instance that's already running, the latter forks off a child process and reads its stdout.

Comment: How should I run this inside the script now? `PWD/subFolder/file.py`? The python code is not supposed to return anything.

Comment: The `$` is not optional. Anyhow, `"$PWD"/subFolder/file.py` will work if this answer is correct (and Python does module lookups relative to a source file given as an absolute path).

Comment: @0stone0, not `${pwd}`, `$PWD`. The variable is all-caps, which puts it in the namespace POSIX reserves for use of the shell and other POSIX-defined tools, whereas other names are guaranteed not to have unintended conflicts on the behavior of standard-defined tools when used by applications for their own purposes. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: Yea, caps for sure, but the `{}` don't matter right?

Comment: Correct, the curly braces don't matter at all in this case; you're not trying to parameterize the expansion, and the character immediately after it isn't valid in a name itself.

Comment: @0stone0, ...that said, I'm curious -- is there a difference in Python module loading behavior between the two cases that leads you to suggest that this answer will make a difference?

Comment: Not `$PWD/someFolder/file.py` but `"$PWD"/someFolder/file.py` -- if you don't have the quotes it'll fail when your directory name has spaces.

Comment: Nah, just included it for readability, but it's probably just a bad habit.